# GMap multicolor line route

Tags: c#, gmap.net

How can I make multicolor line route in GMap WPF (or WinForms ports to WPF application)?

It should present color code of some parameters values (eg color code of speed: red for low speed, green for high speed and "heatmap scale color" for all between low and high) through the route.

I have tried to do it by adding one marker with different color per point, but this solution seems to be not efficient enough, when there is many points. And also there is no line connection between two markers/points.

Maybe there is a way to override render function or something else?

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the route render method draws everything using the same stroke. You will need to inherit the Route class and make your own drawing method, something like:

```
public class GMapRouteColored : GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapRoute
{
    public GMapRouteColored(IEnumerable<PointLatLng> points, string name)
        : base(points, name)
    {

    }

    public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < LocalPoints.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(yourPenForThisLine, LocalPoints[i].X, LocalPoints[i].Y, LocalPoints[i+1].X, LocalPoints[i+1].Y);
        }

    }
}
```

Of course you probably also need a way to determine which pen to use depending on some value of the points. The only easy way I can thing of to handle this is to add a list of integers equal to the number of points you have and use this list as a determination for which pen to use for each local point index. I hope this helps.

Edit: I noticed you are looking for a solution for WPF. The solution I posted will only work for WinForms, however based on my experience using the control, the WinForms has a lot more functionality with overlays and might be better suited for your application.

Comment: Thanks :) I make simple test and it is very good solution. Although I have to make many changes in my code to use WinForms version of GMap in WindowsFormsHost, it seems to be the best what I can do.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you found a major performance difference between using WPF or WinForms? I haven't had the opportunity to research this yet.

Comment: I have tried to find in documentation, but I haven't found any comparision.